# Intuition of ramification: a toy example

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I came across this example in my notes, which aims to offer a simple intuition of the concept of ramification:

Let’s consider the morphism $f: \mathbb{A}_\mathbf{k}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_\mathbf{k}^1 $ defined by the ring homomorphism $\Phi: \mathbf{k}[t] \longrightarrow \mathbf{k}[t]$ sending $t \mapsto t^n$, where $\mathbf{k}$ is algebraically closed. (First problem: does it mean that $t-a \longrightarrow t^n - a$ ? Otherwise I don’t understand also this morphism)

The example continues arguing that each point $x \in \mathbb{A}_\mathbf{k}^1$\ $0$ in the target has exactly $n$ preimages, while $0$ has exactly one.
I think I have understood this only in terms of $\Phi$: for example, letting $z_1, … z_n$ the n roots of 1, the preimages of $t^n-a$ are $\{z_it-a\}$ while clearly for $0$ is just $0$.

I’m not able to see what really happens in the morphism of schemes $f$ except for the fact that, of course, it sends the ideal $(0)$ in the ideal $(0)$.

Let $p$ the point corresponding to the the ideal $I=(t-a)$ for example, what is $f(p)$? Ok, it is the the point corresponding to the ideal $\Phi^{-1}(I)$ which is a prime ideal since $\Phi$ is a morphism, but in this way I’m loosing the information of the n preimages.. I’m very confused.

So my question is: can you help me to understand how does $\Phi$ reflect in terms of ideals in $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a morphism of $k$-algebras $\varphi:R\rightarrow S$ the induced map on affine schemes is
$$
\varphi^*:\mathrm{Spec}(S)\longrightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(R),
\qquad \varphi^*(\frak p)=\phi^{-1}(\frak p)
$$
(note that it is contravariant).

Now you have $R=S=k[t]$ and $\varphi(t)=t^n$.

Let $a\in k$. Since $\varphi(t-a)=(t^n-a)$ (both as elements and ideals) and since
$$
(t^n-a)=\prod_{\zeta\in\mathbf{\mu}_n}(t-\zeta\alpha)\qquad (*)
$$
where $\alpha$ is some fixed $n$-th root of $a$ in $k$ we have
$\phi^{-1}(t-\zeta\alpha)=(t-a)$ as ideals, i.e.
$$
\phi^*:\mathbb{A}^1_k\longrightarrow\mathbb{A}^1_k,\qquad \zeta\alpha\mapsto a=\alpha^n.
$$
This shows that the map is generically $n$-to-$1$ except at $\alpha=0$ where there is ramification. Indeed in the latter case the $n$ ideals in the decomposition $(*)$ coincide.

---

Just for the record: the above holds if the characteristic of $k$ is $0$. If the characteristic of $k$ is $p$ things become messy if $p\mid n$.

Comment: It is very clear. Is there something we can say about the generic point? I mean, does it make sense to ask wether it is ramified? I suppose it is never ramified.

Comment: The generic point maps to the generic point. It is not ramified.